# Prove that the closed unit ball of $L^2[a,b]$ is closed in $L^1[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

**Prove that the closed unit ball of $L^2[a,b]$ is closed in $L^1[a,b]$.**

My friends and I have literally been pouring over this problem for days now without success.  We've been using Hölder's inequality, and especially its special case the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality.  We've also been using Minkowski's (the triangle) Inequality, and also the inequality:

$||f||_{p_1}\leq(b-a)^{\frac{p_2-p_1}{p_1p_2}}\;||f||_{p_2}$ for $1\leq p_1\leq p_2\leq\infty$

The other inequalities being:

$||fg||_1\leq||f||_p\cdot ||f||_q$ for $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ and if $p=1$ then $q=\infty$ (Hölder's)

$||f+g||_p\leq ||f||_p+||g||_p$ (Triangle)

$||fg||_1\leq ||f||_2\cdot ||g||_2$ (Cauchy-Schwarz)

I'll just say that we've been a lot of places with these inequalities, but nowhere we want to go. We defined $A$ to be the closed unit ball in $L^2[a,b]$:

$$A:=\{\;f\in L^2[a,b] : ||f||_2\leq 1\}.$$

And now we want to consider functions in $L^1[a,b]$ (and thus with the $L^1$ metric), and prove that if every open ball around a function contains a point from $A$, then that function is actually in $A$.  Can anyone help us with this?  Thanks.

Comment: Does your "pouring over this problem" have anything to do with your user name? :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can generalize to $L^2(X)$ where $X$ is any measure space and other exponents.

As we are the context of metric spaces, we only need to check sequential closeness. 
Fix $\{f_n\}$ a sequence in the closed unit ball of $L^2(X)$ which converges to $f$ *in $L^1$*; then $\int_X|f_n|^2\leqslant 1$ for all $n$. Now extract from $\{f_n\}$ a sub-sequence which converges almost everywhere and use Fatou's lemma.

Comment: Please, can you expand your answer?

Comment: I can't see why $\int_X |f|^2\leq 1$.

Comment: The subsequence can just be $f_n$ itself right?

Comment: @Tomás Wihtout loss of generality, we can assume that $f_n$ converges to $f$ pointwise (cf extraction as claimed by Davide Giraudo). Now by Fatou $\int |f|^2\leq \liminf \int |f_n|^2\leq 1$.